# Isabelle instantiation with type parameter

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to get this to work

```
no_notation Nil ("[]") and Cons (infixr "#" 65) and append (infixr "@" 65) and plus (infixl "+" 65)


class plus =
  fixes plus :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a"  (infixl "+" 65)

datatype 'a list =
    Nil  ("[]")
    | Cons 'a "'a list"  (infixr "#" 65)

instantiation "'a list" :: plus
begin
  
primrec plus_list :: "'a list ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'a list" where
"plus_list []  ys = ys" |
"plus_list (x#xs) ys = x # (plus_list xs ys)"

instance ..
end
```

essentially lists are free monoids under concatenation. How do I express this fact using type-classes?

At the moment I get

```
Undefined type name: "'a list"⌂
```

in this line

```
instantiation "'a list" :: plus
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

If I get rid of `'a` I get

```
Bad number of arguments for type constructor: "Test.list"
```

Even if I try to specialize to `nat list` I get

```
Undefined type name: "nat list"⌂
```

I can see here
https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/classes.pdf
that it is possible. However, the notation used in this pdf is strange. I can't reproduce any of the examples provided. For instance this

```
class eq where
   eq :: α ⇒ α ⇒ bool
```

I suppose it's meant to be something like

```
class eq where
   eq :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"
```

but when I paste it to jEdit I get syntax error. Other Isabelle tutorials use a different notation, like

```
class eq =
   fixes eq :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"
```

This pdf also provides example

```
instance (α::eq, β::eq) pair :: eq where
    eq (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = eq x1 x2 ∧ eq y1 y2
```

which looks like what I am looking for. An instance of a higher-order type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
no_notation Nil ("[]") and Cons (infixr "#" 65) and append (infixr "@" 65) and plus (infixl "+" 65)


class plus =
  fixes plus :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a"  (infixl "+" 65)

datatype 'a list =
    Nil  ("[]")
    | Cons 'a "'a list"  (infixr "#" 65)

instantiation  list :: (type) plus
begin
  
primrec plus_list :: "'a list ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'a list" where
"plus_list []  ys = ys" |
"plus_list (x#xs) ys = x # (plus_list xs ys)"

instance ..
end
```